# Returning StatusCode from Test-Connection

Tags: powershell

test-connection server | select-object *

returns many properties, among them StatusCode.

How can I return only this value?
My best guess would be

```
$r = test-connection server
$r.statuscode
```

but that doesn't work.
How do I do it?

**EDIT**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx has more information about the statuscode I would like to receive.. No luck yet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Test-Connection` by default will give you a collection (4 `System.Management.ManagementObject` objects). It uses the Win32_PingStatus WMI class internally.

```
(Test-Connection server).GetType().FullName
```

Outputs:

```
System.Object[]
```

So you can do this:

```
(Test-Connection server -Count 1).StatusCode
```

or this:

```
(Test-Connection server)[0].StatusCode
```

Don't forget, some pings may fail so if you just check one it may not necessary mean there's no connection.

You could also try calling `Win32_PingStatus` directly like this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PingStatus -Filter "Address='server'" | Select-Object -Property Address,ResponseTime,StatusCode
```

Comment: That did't work unfortunately.. I've updated my question with more info!

Comment: @Sune what part didn't work? Getting the property value or the particular code you were expecting? It returned the property for me, but try invoking Win32_PingStatus directly with `Get-WmiObject` to see if you get a different status code. I added example code.

Answer (score 2):

```
$r = test-connection computername -count 1
$r.statuscode
```

This works.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just try :

```
$r = Test-Connection server -Quiet
```

$r is a boolean

Comment: Perhaps the OP wants to check for one of the 21 possible codes and take the appropriate action. [Win32_PingStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394350(v=vs.85).aspx)